# Critical points of the product of functions

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

I have to find the critical points/values of the following function:$y = x^{\frac{4}{5}}(x-4)^2$

I know I have to use the first and second derivative test. It has a maximum and a minimum, but I don't understand how to classify $(0, f(0))$. Thanks.

Comment: What did you get for the first derivative, and what information did you get out of that?

Comment: With the first and second derivative you can find the relative minima, relative maxima and saddle points. To find the absolute minima and maxima you have to inspect the limits of the domain. That means that you have to calculate $f(0)$ and the value of $f$ at $x\to \infty$. Then compare these values with the critical points.